# "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" on Azure Web Role with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, castle-windsor, invalidprogramexception

I have a web role that works perfectly on my Development PC (VS2013 & Window 8.1 Enterprise x64), but fails when I publish it to Azure with the following exception:

```
[InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   Castle.Core.ComponentModel.get_Dependencies() +0
   Castle.Core.ComponentModel.AddConstructor(ConstructorCandidate constructor) +264
   Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.Inspectors.ConstructorDependenciesModelInspector.ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model) +535
   Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BuildModel>b__4(IContributeComponentModelConstruction c) +137
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action) +95
   Castle.MicroKernel.ModelBuilder.DefaultComponentModelBuilder.BuildModel(IComponentModelDescriptor[] customContributors) +404
   Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) +283
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) +198
   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryFacility.InitFacility() +745
   Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryFacility.Init() +78
   Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities.AbstractFacility.Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility.Init(IKernel kernel, IConfiguration facilityConfig) +165
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, IFacility facility) +507
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(IFacility facility) +213
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility() +167
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.AddFacility() +138
   PingTree.Journey.WebRole.IoCConfig.RegisterComponents() in d:\Users\Ben\OneDrive\Source\PingTree\JourneyWebRole\PingTree.Journey.WebRole\App_Start\IoCConfig.cs:19
   PingTree.Journey.WebRole.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in d:\Users\Ben\OneDrive\Source\PingTree\JourneyWebRole\PingTree.Journey.WebRole\Global.asax.cs:15

[HttpException (0x80004005): Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +475
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +214
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +203
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +313
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +250

[HttpException (0x80004005): Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +452
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +1017
```

The code for the RegisterComponents method is

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");

    var windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
    windsorContainer.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    windsorContainer.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(assemblyPath)));
    windsorContainer.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient());

    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(windsorContainer));
}
```

Its failing on the windsorContainer.AddFacility method call.

I've tried the usual things, used NuGet to remove Castle.Windsor from the project, deleted the local copy and reinstalled Windsor. Another answer here suggested deleting the local temporary ASP.Net files, I've tried that as well. But every time I publish I get the same problem.

**Update 1**
I've been able to reproduce the problem with the boiler plate azure web role template and the following code

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        windsorContainer.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    }
```

Is anybody using Castle Windsor 3.3 on azure without problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more specific answer would be that it seems to be a problem with IntelliTrace.
The deployments that throw the Invalid program exception, had IntelliTrace enabled. By disabling IntelliTrace and redeploying the solution, and the role initialised and started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what caused the InvalidProgramException. 
BUT, I was able to resolve my issue by deleting the Azure deployment and creating a brand new Visual Studio solution, and publishing that.

Answer (score 0):

We did have same problem and we also use windsor castle 3.3. We too remove intelliTrace from azure publish profile and it magicaly solved this issue.